# SMTP server(smtp.gmail.com) response: 'Username and Password not accepted'

Tags: c++, qt, email, authentication, smtp

I am trying to make a simple **SMTP** client that will send some Emails by using standard **SMTP** *protocol* to the ***smtp.gmail.com*** server over SSL/TLS on ***port 465***.
When I attempt to connect to the server I get the following **response**:

> 250 smtp.gmail.com at your service\r\n

But when I try to **authenticate** the user like:

```
QString userpass = QLatin1Char('\0') + gmail + QLatin1Char('\0') + pass;
write(soc, QByteArrayLiteral("AUTH PLAIN ") + userpass.toLatin1().toBase64());
//note in write i am appending request with \r\n
```

I get the following **response** from the server:

> 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\r\n535
> 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials r17-20200a...wru.27 - gsmtp\r\n

I **visited** the link but it was useless as I cannot use the *2 steps verification* facility on **CLI**. What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Generate an application password or enable insecure apps (as stated in your link)

Comment: Note that Gmail *really* doesn't want you enabling "insecure apps". Per https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255: "*To help keep your account secure, starting May 30, 2022, ​​Google will no longer support the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.*" The preferred way to login to Gmail is via OAuth 2.0: https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol